# Javascript: Elements From Two Div ID's

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid, concatenation

I need to select all the anchor elements in two different navigation panels.  What's the best way to do so?  Effective &/or efficient.

Option 1: I can set each nav to a class, look for the class, grab all the anchors within each div with that class.

Option 2: I can set each nav with an ID.  For some reason I had trouble concat the two arrays of anchors from each div id.  Any idea why, are they arrays?  Ex.

```
<code>
var nav = document.getElementById("nav").getElementsByTagName("a");
var subnav = document.getElementById("subnav").getElementsByTagName("a");

var allnav = nav.concat(subnav); // Didn't seem to work

// neither did this.  Just seemed to break.     
for(var i=0;i<subnav.length;i++){ 
   nav.push(subnav[i]);
}
</code>
```

Option 3: Get each div by ID.  Send to function to loop through, get anchors, and do appropriate action.

Which would be quicker or use less resources, &/or which do you think would be more maintainable?

I know there's an excellent method with jQuery, but given my snippet is quite short, I'd prefer not to add the entire library for just a few small functions.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You are close:

```
var allnav = []; // initialise allnav as an array

// Store length of NodeList, slight performance boost in some browsers
// and is just neater
for (var i=0, iLen=subnav.length; i<iLen; i++) { 
   allnav.push(subnav[i]);

   // or

   allnav[i] = subnav[i];
}
```

Don't use `Array.prototype.slice.call()` because you should not treat host objects like native ECMAScript objects, e.g. it will fail in IE < 9. There is no specification anywhere to say that host objects must behave like native ECMA-262 objects (and ECMA-262 expressly says they don't have to).

Note that there is also a [document.anchors](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-7577272) collection and a [document.links](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-7068919) collection (which are not mutually exclusive, an A element can be an anchor, a link or both).

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByTagName` returns a `NodeList`. A `NodeList` is not an `Array`.

`NodeList` however is array like and can be converted to an array using `toArray`

```
var toArray = function _toArray(obj) {
     var arr = [];
     for (var i = 0, ii = obj.length; i < ii; i++) {
          arr.push(obj[i]);
     }
     return arr;
};

var allnav = toArray(nav).concat(subnav);
```

Alternatively you can use `Array.prototype.slice.call(nav)` to convert a `NodeList` to an `Array`.

You could also add a class `anchor-nav` to both nav's and then use `querySelectorAll`.

`var anchors = document.querySelectorAll("nav.anchor-nav a");`

Comment: Don't treat host objects like native objects and don't use *for..in* as NodeLists have named properties that are not appropriate to copy to an Array (like the *item* method). Iterate using a for loop and counter.

Comment: That is hands down the strangest way I have ever seen to convert a NodeList to an Array. Actually, I'm pretty sure it won't work, though it would if you changed `var arr = [];` to `var arr = Array(obj.length);`...

Comment: @RobG: Because the `Array` constructor -- which `new` is optional for (ES5 15.4.1) -- creates a new array of length `n` when called with a single integer argument `n` (ES5 15.4.2.2). That object has `n+1` own properties, `0..n` and `length`. Iterating over the created Array with a `for-in` loop with `hasOwnProperty` (`for (var k in arr) { if (obj.hasOwnProperty(k))` (see the next comment) will yield those properties, which he then looked up in the object he was converting to an array and copied over to the new array (`arr.push(obj[k]);`.

Comment: @RobG: Note that he's doing the `hasOwnProperty` on `obj`, not on `arr`, but it doesn't matter since `obj` has `0..n` and `length` properties also.

Answer (score 0):

```
var slice = document.body instanceof Object ? // IE < 9 has some really weird issues
    Array.prototype.slice : function () {
        for (var array = [], i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; ++i)
            array[i] = this[i];
    };

var nav = slice.call(document.getElementById("nav").getElementsByTagName("a"));
var subnav = slice.call(document.getElementById("subnav").getElementsByTagName("a"));

var allnav = nav.concat(subnav); // Will work now.
```

`getElementsByTagName` doesn't return an Array, it returns a NodeList, which doesn't have a `concat` method. The `slice.call` stuff converts the NodeList into a real Array. Alternatively, it is more efficient to do

```
nav.push.apply(nav, subnav);
// nav is now the equivalent of allnav
```

Comment: `nav.push.apply(nav, subnav)`

Comment: Hey, I've been drive-by down voted!! Whoo hoo!! I am now truely iducted into the Stackoverflow hall of arsehats. Yes!! Whoever did it didn't even have the guts to say who they were, so I appologise for not returning the compliment.